# Bash: How to move files and directories from one directory to another?

Tags: bash, mv

I'm trying to write a script that moves files and (sub)directories from within one directory to another. That move operation should include not only regular files and directories but also any dot-files. So far I've come up with this:

```
mv -f "$SOURCE_DIR"/.?? "$TARGET_DIR"
mv -f "$SOURCE_DIR"/.??* "$TARGET_DIR"
mv -f "$SOURCE_DIR"/* "$TARGET_DIR"
```

But these commands fail if there are no files matching the patterns.

I need this move operation to succeed in any case ..

- regardless of the file name
- regardless if there are no files at all
- regardless of the type: file, link, directory, etc.

But I need the operation to fail if something goes wrong completely (e.g. insufficient privileges at the target directory, etc.) so just ignoring any errors is not a good option.

How to I solve this problem? I guess there is a very simple solution to that which I overlooked.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably making this harder than you need to.

```
mv $srcdir $destdir
```

Comment: You're right. But only in this very specific case: I can abandon the source directory as well and move it to the target as is. I came up with the existing solution in the first place as I though I could *not* remove the source directory ... So I guess your answer perfectly solves my problem (Thank you!!!) but I guess it does not answer the question ... ;-)

Comment: So what should I do? Accept it as it solves my problem? It DOES solve my problem ... (Thank you!!!)

Comment: if that answers your questions please give them the acceptance